# Jenkins wont pass the arguments to powershell script as expected

Tags: powershell, shell, jenkins, groovy

I have below jenkins pipeline script which calls another powershell script with some arguments:

Jenkins script:

```
def map = setupMap()
def setupMap() {
    def map = [:]
    if (env.JOB_NAME.startsWith("jen-dev")) { 
        map['jenkinsCredentialsKey'] = 'dev-jenkins'
        map['region'] = 'us-west-1'
        map['jenkinsRole'] = 'svc.jenkins'
        map['sbAWSAccountID'] = 'accountID'
        map['sbBucketname'] = 'sa-codedeploy'
        map['AWSAccountID'] = 'id2'
        map['CredentialsKey'] = 'gc-dev'

    }  else {
        // noop
    }
    return map
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image IMAGE_AWSCLI_PS
            args '-v /etc/pki:/etc/pki:ro'
        }
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder logRotator(numToKeepStr: '200')
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        durabilityHint 'PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED'
        disableResume()
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {
        stage('test comment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    params = [:]
                    params['credentials'] = map['jenkinsCredentialsKey']
                    params['region'] =  map['region'] 
                    params['role'] = map['jenkinsRole']
                    params['roleAccount'] = map['sbAWSAccountID']
                    def sbBucketname = map['sbBucketname']
                    withAWS(params) {
                        sh '''
                            bucketname='''+sbBucketname+'''

                            # copy the build plan to current directory
                            aws s3 cp s3://$bucketname/PSScript.ps1 .
                        '''
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
        stage('call PS script') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def credentials = map['CredentialsKey']
                    withAWS(region: 'us-west-1', credentials: credentials) {
                            sh '''
                                userID = 'tets'
                                password = 'password'
                                pwsh -NonInteractive -File ./PSScript.ps1 $userID $password
                            '''
                    }                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `PSScript.ps1` file:

```
$userIDArg = $args[0];
$passwordArg = $args[1];

function CreateUser($userID, $password) { 
       $Params = @{
        Comment = 'Create a SQL user'
        DocumentName = 'AWS-RunPowerShellScript'
        Targets = @(
        @{
            Key = 'InstanceIds'
            Values = @(
                "i-instanceID"
            )
        })
        Parameters = @{
           commands = @(
           Write "'$userID $password'"   #This line prints empty userid and password
       ) 
        }
    }
    $JsonStr = $Params | ConvertTo-Json  -Depth 4
    $FileName = 'SSMCommandTempFile-' + $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss) + '.json'
    $FilePattern = 'file://' + $FileName
    $JsonStr | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding ASCII
    aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --cli-input-json $FilePattern
    Remove-Item $FileName
}

CreateUser $userIDArg $passwordArg
```

So the line where I am printing the userID and password arguments in CreateUser method, prints empty values.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You are starting powershell inside the shell on Linux? %-) I don't see the line where you are printing userid...

Comment: Yes, I am executing the powershell inside the shell script. I am printing the userid in ps script, `CreateUser` method (command).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try an alternative, you can define parameters for your script (like a function).

`PSScript.ps1` with named parameters:

```
param($userID, $password)

$Params = @{
Comment = 'Create a SQL user'
DocumentName = 'AWS-RunPowerShellScript'
Targets = @(
@{
    Key = 'InstanceIds'
    Values = @(
        "i-instanceID"
    )
})
Parameters = @{
    commands = @(
        Write "'$userID $password'"   #This line prints empty userid and password
    ) 
}
}
$JsonStr = $Params | ConvertTo-Json  -Depth 4
$FileName = 'SSMCommandTempFile-' + $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss) + '.json'
$FilePattern = 'file://' + $FileName
$JsonStr | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding ASCII
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --cli-input-json $FilePattern
Remove-Item $FileName
```